# the following functional equation it is useful?

Tags: calculus

I can resolve equation as $$-\text{f1}(s+3)+\frac{\text{f1}(s+i)}{s+1}=1$$
but i do know any aplication of it xe the result of equation above it is
$$-1+\frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) \, _2F_1\left(1,\left(\frac{3}{10}+\frac{i}{10}\right) ((1-i)+s);\left(\frac{3}{10}+\frac{i}{10}\right) ((4-2 i)+s);4-i\right)}{s+(1-i)}$$ this type the equation are very complicate of resolve, also it is possible to resolve more complicate equation as $$\frac{\frac{\partial ^n\text{f1}(k+s)}{\partial x^n}}{s+1}-\frac{\text{f1}(m+s)}{Q(s)}=P(s)$$ where P,Q are polynomials
Could you indicate if this type of equation have any application ? in physiscs or in any fields ofany science, also if you want i could try resolve your functional equation
Thanks.